# Why does fgets adds a space at the end of string?

Tags: php, string, compare, fopen, cat

I have a file which contains a single string.
I open the file and read the value, with fopen and fgets, i noticed that a space is added at the end of the string.

```
$file = fopen("myfile", "r") or exit("<br><p>Unable to open file</p><br>");
$mystring= fgets($file);
fclose($file);
```

Content of myfile:

```
Hello
```

Test

```
echo "<p>'".$mystring."'</p>";    //Output:   'Hello '
```

As you can see there is now a space at the end of the string, even though there is no space in the file.

I tried the same with the linux command "cat":

```
$mystring = shell_exec("cat myfile");
echo "<p>'".$mystring."'</p>";    //Output:   'Hello '
```

Still a space at the end of the string.

My goal is to compare the string in the file, with a value in my code.

```
if ($mystring === "Hello")
{
    echo "Equal";
}
else
{
    echo "not equal";
}
```

I always get "not equal".
How can i read and store the actual file content into my variable?

Comment: You can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). Do the actual file contents have a newline? Was the file created with an editor which is not text friendly? There are many reasons the space can be there.

Comment: No, because then if the file content is `'hello '` ('hello' with space at the end) then i loose the space at the end. I need the actual content.
The file was created with "nano", i also tried gedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug a string, try this:

```
foreach(str_split($mystring) as $chr) {
    printf("[%02x] %s <br />",ord($chr),$chr);
}
```

This should, in your case, yield something like...

> [48] H
>   [65] e
>   [6c] l
>   [6c] l
>   [6f] o
>   [0a]

Take note of that last one. `0x0a` is a newline character, which is what all lines of text obtained through `fgets` and `shell_exec` end with, since that's what marks the end of the line (both functions return a "line" of output from their respective activity).

(Note: You may get `[0c] [0a]`, or a CRLF, depending on your system.)

To fix, just use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) on the string before handling it.

EDIT: Since you added in a comment that the case of `'hello '` should be allowed, then you can use something more explicit, like `rtrim($mystring, "\r\n");`

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! It works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

) There's quite a number of things that could be wrong. I would start with inspecting the variable contents - Debugging if you can, or use a var_dump.

A nice way to get around the problem would be to use file_get_contents() instead (http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php). I think that is exactly made for this kind of problems ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunattely i still get "not equal"

Comment: Ok. so the problem is not in opening and reading the file content. I think "Niet" has the problem at its root, your file contains probably more than just the 5 characters of "Hello". A new-line maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the case of differences in line endings like MsDos, Unix or Mac. You can use the function auto_detect_line_endings. (More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings)).

Or you can simply trim the text from the output file before comparison as given below.

```
$file = fopen("myfile", "r") or exit("<br><p>Unable to open file</p><br>");
$mystring= fgets($file);
$mystring= trim($mystring);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then if the file content would be "Hello " (Hello with space at the end) then i would change the original value, but i dont want to change the value. I just wan't to get the actual value and store it in a variable.

Comment: So if you have a hello without the trailing space then fgets should get an EOF or a next line char. Which it will figure out using the auto_detect_line_endings function/directive I mentioned in my answer.

Then perhaps you won't have to use the trim and alter the original text.